# How to make running total in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate a Running Total in SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

I am creating a transaction table. Ive decided not to store the balance of each user anywhere. What I am plannign to do is, every month I will "BRING BALANCE FORWARD" and caclulate the balance from the balance bought forward MINUS debits PLUS credits.

My table looks like this

```
ID int primary key
userID int foriegn key
TransactionDate datetime
description varchar(200)
amount money
balanceBoughtForward bit
```

I am planning on writting a function that gets the latest record that is a balanceeboughtforward, then using that id to calculate the balance with the running total in a view with an extra column "BALANCE"

But I cant figure out how to create a running total column?

Comment: Also, if you're on SQL 2012, the running total is a more efficient query. Not really sure how your `balanceBoughtForward` is supposed to act though (also has a typo)

Comment: Can I assume the column "BALANCE" will have only one row that is not null at any given time?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not getting it or your question isn't clear enough. Isn't this solved with an aggregate function (the SUM function more precisely).

Ex:

```
select user_id, (sum(credit) - sum(debit)) balance
from table
where
some condition
group by
user_id
```

Comment: Look up "Running Total" and check the answer linked to by @billinkc